# SVG files and wordpress

Tags: images, apache, xampp

I have a website and I would like to use SVG files so that certain images are dynamic but when i upload them it displays as an unknown file and when I set them as a featured image for a post the preview box shows it properly but when you view the image on the page (outside of WP-Admin) it does not show.

I have checked the MIME settings and they are configured properly. I did this by checking an SVG file with the W3C checker tool and looking in the `mime.types` file.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Thanks!

---

Stats:
Server Software: `XAMPP for Windows`
CPU: `AMD FX-4300`
RAM: `32GB`
HDDs: `2 - 1TB HDDs RAID 1, 3 - 1TB HDDs Storage spaces as ReFS`
Mobo: `M5A99FX Pro R2.0, latest BIOS`
OS: `Windows 10 Pro x64`
WordPress info: `Wordpress 4.3`
WordPress Plugins: `Akismet, Custom Login, Google Analytics by Yoast, Jetpack, Shortcodes Ultimate, WP-Mail-SMTP, WP-PageNavi and Yoast SEO`
Themes: `Hueman, Twenty Fifteen and Unite`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to edit your `functions.php` file and add a few lines.

This article has a better explanation. I suggest you try here if you haven't already.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/allow-svg-through-wordpress-media-uploader/

Comment: I have unlimited file types allowed to be uploaded already using the Wp-Config.php `define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOAFS', true);` So I do not think along the upload will help... Thanks for the thought!